# PHP Regular Expression to change internal links to absolute links

Tags: php, regex, curl, anchor

I am looking for a regular expression in PHP that can replace the `href` attribute of anchor tags and  `src` attribute of IMG, style, scripts, etc when they are internal.

an example: if I am looking at the page `http://www.mysite.com` and on that page there is an image:

`<img src="/images/picture.gif />` then I want to be able to change that into:

`<img src="http://mysite.com/images/picture.gif />`

The same thing for anchor tags: `<a href="otherpage.php" >foo</a>` should be changed to

`<a href="http://mysite.com/otherpage.php" >foo</a>`

Also, it should be able to work on other elements that have a `src=` or a `href=` attribute, and it should work on elements that have one or more other attributes as well  (eg `<img class="test" src="/images/picture.gif alt="some picture" />`)

I tried something like

```
preg_replace("/src=[\"']([\/])(.*)?[\"'] /", "src='".$domain."/$2'", $htmldata);
```

but this did not work well. It took the src attribute, but it captured all the attributes after the src as well. Also, it didn't capture strings that did not start with a / (e.g. `src="image.png"` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change greediness with U modifier and allow for zero leading slashes:

```
 /(?:src|href)\s*=\s*[\"\'](?:\/*)([\w\.]*)[\"\']/U
```

...and since you don't need src|href or the leading slash as a backreference, match but omit them with ?:

Then, the image name becomes $1 instead of $2.

My use of the U modifier on the whole pattern is because, when ? is otherwise present as in ?: and I don't need additional granularity, my eyes see it more clearly.

Although, as others have pointed out, doing this by regex likely isn't the Best One True Answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest keeping them as "internal" links, and simply adding an HTML [base tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-base-element). Hopefully your intended use allows for this solution.

EDIT : I (@ManseUK) changed the link to be the w3.org site rather than <strike>w3schools</strike>[w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) - Hope you dont mind ....

Comment: Or perhaps the OPs next venture into RegExp's will be to change the domain name !!!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use this in my application. However, this is a great answer, and I love it. +1 ;)

Comment: @ManseUK, I don't mind the change since the content is there, but I find w3schools easier to read.

Comment: @Mikhail it might be easier to read - but its not always correct ...I changed the link to the official definition site.

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern out

```
(src|href)\s*=\s*[\'\"]\/(.*?)[\'\"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/';
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=href=[\'"]|src=[\'"])\/?/', $url.'$1', $input);
```